# "Abweichen" vs "unterscheiden"

Tags: difference, verb-choice

> Deutsch unterscheidet sich vom Niederländischen.
>
> Deutsch weicht vom Niederländischen ab.

Wann und in welchem Zusammenhang kann man **abweichen** verwenden? Ist **sich unterscheiden** gängiger als **abweichen**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Allgemein kann man *abweichen* und *unterscheiden* synonym verwenden. *unterscheiden* ist ein wenig stärker, meistens kommt es auf den Kontext an.

> *abweichen* (tech.) wird z.B. verwendet, wenn gemessene Werte nicht in einem Toleranzbereich liegen oder vorgegebene Werte nicht exakt erreichen.
>
> *abweichen* (naut.) wird verwendet, wenn z.B. ein Schiff den vorgegebenen Kurs nicht einhält oder davon abkommt.

im Duden wird *abweichen* wie folgt beschrieben:

> 1. eine eingeschlagene Richtung verlassen, sich von ihr entfernen
> 2. verschieden sein, sich unterscheiden

http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/abweichen_abbiegen_sich_unterscheiden

*unterscheiden* wird häufig für signifikante Unterschiede bei bestimmten Attributen oder Eigenschaften verwendet.

Im Duden wird *unterscheiden* wie folgt beschrieben:

> 1. a. etwas im Hinblick auf seine besonderen Merkmale, Eigenschaften
>      o. Ä. erkennen und es als etwas, was nicht oder nur teilweise mit
>      etwas anderem übereinstimmt, bestimmen
>
> b. einen Unterschied machen
>
> c. zwischen zwei oder mehreren Dingen, Erscheinungen o. Ä. einen
>   Unterschied feststellen, wahrnehmen; als etwas Verschiedenes, in
>   seiner Verschiedenheit erkennen
>
> 2. im Hinblick auf bestimmte Merkmale, Eigenschaften o. Ä. anders sein als eine andere Person oder Sache
> 3. das besondere Merkmal sein, worin jemand, etwas von jemandem, etwas abweicht
> 4. etwas unter, zwischen etwas anderem, vielem anderen in seinen Einzelheiten optisch oder akustisch wahrnehmen

http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/unterscheiden

Die Bedeutung beider Wörter ist nicht scharf trennbar. Ins Englische würde ich die Worte wie folgt übersetzen:

> abweichen = deviate
>
> unterscheiden = differ

Comment: o.O Du hast recht... Ich bin so im bilingualen Kontext unterwegs, dass mir das gar nicht aufgefallen ist. Ich formuliere die Antwort um ... Oha. Sorry ^^

Comment: Im Englischen *deviate* steckt ja auch das lateinische *deviare* (wenn man es ganz wörtlich nimmt also *vom Weg gehen*) drin. Daher steckt hinter *abweichen* gedanklich die Entwicklung hin zum Ist-Zustand. *unterscheiden* beschreibt diesen Ist-Zustand.

Answer (score 4):

Es kommt darauf an, welche Voraussetzung man annimmt:

Wenn sich eine Sache von einer anderen **unterscheidet**, dann hat sie bezüglich eines oder mehrerer Kriterien keine Gemeinsamkeit mit einer anderen Sache. Wichtig ist, dass es auch sein kann, dass sich beide Dinge in **allen** Eigenschaften unterscheiden können.

Beispiel

> Ein Auto unterscheidet sich von einem Apfel.
>   Die beiden Mercedes SLK unterscheiden sich nur in der Farbe (der eine ist rot, der andere grün)

Wenn eine Sache von einer anderen Sache **abweicht**, dann geht man zumeist davon aus, dass sie einen gemeinsamen Ursprung haben oder sich zumindest in wichtigen Eigenschaften ähneln.

Beispiel

> Sportwagen und Kombis sind beide Autos, weichen aber beispielsweise unter anderem in Form und Motorisierung voneinander ab.
>   Die beiden Mercedes SLK sind beide rot, aber die Farbtöne weichen etwas voneinander ab

Natürlich ist es so, dass sich zwei voneinander abweichende Farbtöne auch unterscheiden, jedoch ist die Konnotation von **abweichen** und **unterscheiden** ein bisschen anders, wie oben beschrieben.

Und es gibt auch Mischaussagen wie: `A` weicht von `B` in *allen Punkten* ab. Das heißt natürlich implizit, dass `A` und `B` komplett unterschiedlich sind. Dennoch ist hier der Grundgedanke, dass `A` ursprünglich aus `B` hervorgegangen ist, sich aber jetzt in eine andere Richtung weiterentwickelt hat.

Man könnte also auch sagen, dass **abweichen** eine Entwicklung impliziert, während **unterscheiden** den Ist-Zustand darlegt.

Answer (score 3):

Zwei wichtige Unterschiede sind:

*Unterscheiden* kann auch transitiv verwendet werden:

> Ich unterscheide verschiedene Farbtöne.

*Abweichen* wird häufig für Wege (oder im übertragenen Sinn auch Lösungswege) verwendet und impliziert ein Normal, also einen Standardweg oder ein theoretischen Wert, von dem der tatsächlich eingeschlagene Weg bzw. gemessene Wert abweicht. Von daher hat *abweichen* immer einen negativen Unterton.

Comment: Ich finde nicht, dass *abweichen* einen negativen Unterton hat.

Comment: @guidot Was ist an *Pestalozzi wich in seinen Erziehungsmethoden stark von der zu seiner Zeit gängigen starken Orientierung an Autorität und Gewalt ab* für ein "negativer Unterton" drin? Wenn man von etwas Negativem abweicht, kann das durchaus positiv sein.